# I keep getting errors when setting up my server with npm run dev. How can I fix the 'cannot find module' error shown in the image provided?

Tags: javascript, node-modules, nodemon

Good day.

Please i don't know what to do regarding setup my server with npm run dev, i keep errors, when i fix one error another seems to come up, the one i am having right now is shown on the picture i uploaded with this complain [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYFBU.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COk8r.png)

This error has kept me stocked and i cant move forward in my project.

node:Internal/error:490 ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err); Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND] cannot find module 'C:\Users|Bright\Desktop\Martaf\backend\app.mjs imported from C:Users\Bright\Desktop\Martaf\backend\server.js

I keep getting error

What can i do fix it?

Comment: Can you just rename server.mjs to server.js? If you don't use import statements it should just work...